# Called for French Visa interview

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas

I am very worried and looking for some hope. My husband and I are planning to travel to London, Paris and Amsterdam on the 15th of Sep, 2016 from India. We already got our UK visa but due to some last minute leave approval issues in my husband's office, we applied for schengen visa from France at the last moment (with just about 15 days left for the trip). Yesterday my husband got a call from the French Embassy asking us to come for an interview on the 8th. Since there are normally no interviews for tourist visa, does this mean there is a high chance of visa rejection? Also, as we are planning to travel on the 15th, not sure whether we will receive our passports back in time for, if not, we will not even be able to travel to the UK and the entire trip will go down the drain.

Note: We already have valid US and UK visas and have travelled to US last year as tourists.

Comment: Interviewing tourist applicants is coming back into vogue, everybody will be doing it soon. It doesn't mean there's a high chance of refusal,

Comment: In addition to @GayotFow, kindly carry your tickets and travel itinerary/bookings along with you, it might help in fast processing of visa and reduce chance of rejection. As itinerary/bookings will justify your intent for travel.

Comment: If they were planning on refusing, they probably wouldn't waste their time with an interview.

Comment: @CMaster..but maybe it's part of the EU agreement to give everyone a fair chance..I am more worried because we have not been specifically asked to bring any documents so really not sure what this is about:(

Comment: About application processing time, French consulates in India try to dispose applications within 2-3 business days so if your interview goes well and application is accepted, you should receive your passport well before your intended departure.

Comment: It is now necessary to show up at the consulate to have your biometrics registered in a database. Might that be the purpose of this interview?

Comment: Here in the US, I've had Schengen Visa twice in the last 3 years and both times I was asked to appear in-person for interview and fingerprints.

Answer (score 2):

As @GayotFow mentioned:

> Interviewing tourist applicants is coming back into vogue, everybody
>   will be doing it soon. It doesn't mean there's a high chance of
>   refusal

Just because you were asked for a personal meeting doesn't mean you are likely to be rejected, it's simply a standard procedure on behalf of the embassy. The interview might also be conducted in order to collect fingerprints/biometrics, assuming you haven't been to the Schengen area in the past 5 years.

So the answer is: **no**, it doesn't mean you are likely to be rejected.